# External monitor connected at boot in 14,04

Tags: 14.04

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.
Ever since if I boot up with the external monitor plugged in (to Dell Lattitude D430 laptop) both screens come up but no program menus or task bar - just the wallpaper.
I have to Ctrl + Alt + F1 to get terminal to shutdown and re-start with VGA cable unplugged.
Without VGA plugged in it boots fine and then I can plug VGA in and it works fine with correct settings resolution etc.
The problem never occurred in 12.04.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Grant

Answer (score 0):

**[`ARandR`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/arandr/)** is your friend,

> ARandR is a visual front end for XRandR 1.2/1.3 (per display options),
>   which provides full controll over positioning, saving and loading
>   to/from shell scripts and easy integration with other applications.

[image]

`sudo apt-get install arandr`

or get it from [Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/arandr/)

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: I added some addtional info, thank you very much for attention mate.